# How do you create a Blazor WebAssembly website connected to a database with CRUD functions

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to get deeper into blazor. I want to build a website that can use CRUD functions connected to a database.
I use Microsoft SQL Server along with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio 2019 on .Net Core/ASP.NET CORE 5.

Comment: Search the internet for "Blazor Database CRUD". You'll find articles and Youtube videos.  There's a set of articles here - https://shauncurtis.github.io/Building-a-Database-Application-in-Blazor/ - describing the framework/methodology I use.

Comment: You don't, just like any SPA web app. You create a server-side API and call it.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  Are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [old sample project](https://github.com/KorzhCom/EasyData/tree/master/samples/EasyDataBasicDemo.BlazorWebAsm.Net5), the new is [this project](https://github.com/KorzhCom/EasyData/tree/master/samples/EasyDataBasicDemo.BlazorWebAsm.Net6) of a Blazor WebAsm solution that implements CRUD for a database accessed via EF Core. It's based on EasyData open-source library.

Answer (score 5):

You don't, is the simple answer.  Blazor WebAssembly is still website running in a browser and hence has very limited access to the client machine.

To do this you have two layers, the website in Blazor WASM, which calls WebAPI's on another layer (a basic ASPNET Core WebAPI).  This API layer, as its sits on your server, can access databases and other resources.  Blazor WASM is no different to Angular, Vue or React in this way.

Another alternative is Blazor Server, as in effect everything is running on your server and not the client.

Comment: Even with Blazor Server, it's not as simple as connecting to the database or using a DbContext. Blazor Server is also stateful, and unless connections or EF contexts are disposed explicitly, they remain open as long as the user's "circuit" is active. Even with Blazor Server, it's better to call a "service"

Comment: Not entirely true. EF Core does not keep the connection open. When a DB operation needs to happen, a new connections is retrieved from the connection pool, the operation is performed and then the connection is closed and returned to the pool. This does not happen on Dispose. It happens under the hood. It is perfectly safe to use DbContext directly from a Blazor application.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is entirely wrong. The lifespan of the context can be fine tuned to whichever lifetime you want. Use DbContext factory if you need transient, using OwningComponent if you need it to match it to the lifetime of the component. Use session/singleton if you need to match it to the scope of a service.

Comment: @MayurEkbote that comment contradicts itself (if it's wrong, why is fine tuning needed?) and the documentation. The article [ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0). The opening paragraphs states: `Blazor Server is a stateful app framework. The app maintains an ongoing connection to the server, and the user's state is held in the server's memory in a circuit. One example of user state is data held in dependency injection (DI) service instances that are scoped to the circuit.`

Comment: @MayurEkbote you can find more details in the [Service Lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#service-lifetime-1) section of `ASP.NET Core Blazor dependency injection`. So, instead of spreading such lifetime management in component code, it's better to hide it in a service.

Comment: You are confusing between SignalR connection which is maintained by the server with the browser and connection maintained between server and a backend database. Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @TinyTownSoftware I never said EF Core keeps connections open - not unless someone started a database transaction. I wrote more or less what the docs say- Blazor Server is stateful and the circuit is the scope. Which makes using injected DbContexts tricky, as several SO questions show. Lots of people found out they get the same DbContext from one page to another when they expected a fresh one

Comment: @MayurEkbote funny, since I said *you* should read it first. I could also point to several SO questions that found that the same DbContext instance was used from one page to another, when people expected to get a new one. That's *very* bad, because it means the changes they thought were discarded when they navigated away are still active and will be persisted when `SaveChanges` is called

Comment: @MayurEkbote as for `with the browser and connection maintained between server and a backend database.` who ever said about any kind of connection between a browser and a database? The browser can't connect to any database - not unless there's an HTTP API in front

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oops. I meant to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

Comment: Yes. It happens. You also get InvalidOperationException. Therefore you need to choose the correct lifetime - function : DbContextFactory, Component: OwningComponentBase , Custom : Session/Singleton